# Beamer: Frame number on header line

Tags: beamer, header-footer, page-numbering

I am using a customized Copenhagen theme, where my header line is redefined like

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\nointerlineskip  
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.75ex,dp=1.375ex,left]{frametitle}
\hspace*{2ex}\strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
\end{beamercolorbox}}
```

Now, I want to add the frame numbering on the right side of this header line as shown in the image. [image]

It would be more helpful, if I can set the size (small or tiny) of the numbers too...

Thanks in advance and waiting for reply...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Usually it is best to give a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing your set-up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\nointerlineskip  
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.75ex,dp=1.375ex]{frametitle}
        \hspace*{2ex}\insertframetitle \hfill {\tiny\insertframenumber} \hspace*{1ex}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}}


\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{test}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{test}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wavoo, that was a quick and wonderful answer !
Thank you very much Sam...

Comment: If this solved your problem please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below the vote count